# Azure DevOps Sprint Capacity in PowerBi using REST API

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, capacity-planning, powerbi-rest-api

I am trying to read the Sprint Capacity from Azure DevOps to PowerBi using REST API.

[image]
I get this error, any solution to fix this?

*DataFormat.Error: We found extra characters at the end of JSON input.
Details:
Value=
Position=4*

[image]

Comment: What does the Web.Contents step return?

Answer (score 1):

I can use the VSTS.Contents to get the capacities, please try to use the following Query:

```
let
    Source = VSTS.Contents("https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/{iterationId}/capacities/{userId}?api-version=6.0"),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromRecords({Json.Document(Source)})
in
    #"Converted to Table"
```